# Glide image stretched

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Hey i am using glide for image downloading , the image being shown in the image view is being stretched (vertically) , after a few search i found that the u need to define scale type to fitXY , i did that but that also doesn't seems to work .

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUrl +".png")
   .fitCenter()
   .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
      @Override
      public boolean onException(Exception e,
                                 String model,
                                 Target<GlideDrawable> target,
                                 boolean isFirstResource)
      {
         return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource,
                                     String model,
                                     Target<GlideDrawable> target,
                                     boolean isFromMemoryCache,
                                     boolean isFirstResource)
      {
         icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }).into(icon);
```

Does anyone has clue what i am doing wrong ??

Comment: use centerCrop() instead of fitCenter()?

Comment: did that already , still the same

Answer (score 3):

After searching for few hours I got this solution.

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user_image).apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100)).into(ImageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `centerCrop` like this

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
  .load(imageUrl)
  .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
    setPlaceHolderImage(contactImage, backgroundColor);
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
      return false;
    }
  })
  .centerCrop()
  .into(contactImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey i am using glide for image downloading , the image being shown in
>   the image view is being stretched (vertically) , after a few search i
>   found that the u need to define scale type to fitXY , i did that but
>   that also doesn't seems to work .

Firstly, streching in Image has nothing to do with Glide Library. And, you can use `centreCrop` to resolve streching issue in image view.

If you wants to have fixed image size. use `adjustViewBounds` set to `true`